# NancyFx + Mono: Unable to resolve type: Nancy.NancyEngine

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, mono, nancy

I just upgraded to mono 4.8.0.

When running my nancy app, I now get this undescriptive error:

```
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.InvalidOperationException: Something went wrong when trying to satisfy one of the dependencies during composition, make sure that you've registered all new dependencies in the container and inspect the innerexception for more details. ---> Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCResolutionException: Unable to resolve type: Nancy.NancyEngine ---> Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCResolutionException: Unable to resolve type: Nancy.Routing.DefaultRequestDispatcher ---> Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCResolutionException: Unable to resolve type: Nancy.Routing.DefaultRouteResolver ---> Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCResolutionException: Unable to resolve type: Nancy.Routing.RouteCache ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

It says that there are some dependencies not properly registered. However, usually, this get accompanied (down the chain of inner exceptions) with a indication with dependency is not able to get resolved.

Now it just says `Unable to resolve type: Nancy.NancyEngine`, which is a class I am sure I should not need to modify for this. Also, at the end of the stacktrace (where there is usually a clue as to which dependency is causing this), it shows `Unable to resolve type: Nancy.Routing.RouteCache ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

Below is the full stack trace. What am I missing? Thank you for any insight into this matter!

```
Stack overflow in unmanaged: IP: 0x1bec8c, fault addr: 0xbf767fec
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.InvalidOperationException: Something went wrong when trying to satisfy one of the dependencies during composition, make sure that you've registered all new dependencies in the container and inspect the innerexception for more details. ---> Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCResolutionException: Unable to resolve type: Nancy.NancyEngine ---> Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCResolutionException: Unable to resolve type: Nancy.Routing.DefaultRequestDispatcher ---> Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCResolutionException: Unable to resolve type: Nancy.Routing.DefaultRouteResolver ---> Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCResolutionException: Unable to resolve type: Nancy.Routing.RouteCache ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
   at System.Exception..ctor (System.String message, System.Exception innerException) in <filename unknown>:line 0
   at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCResolutionException..ctor (System.Type type, System.Exception innerException) in <filename unknown>:line 0
   at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer.ResolveInternal (Nancy.TinyIoc.TypeRegistration registration, Nancy.TinyIoc.NamedParameterOverloads parameters, Nancy.TinyIoc.ResolveOptions options) in <filename unknown>:line 0
   at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer.<ResolveAllInternal>b__43 (Nancy.TinyIoc.TypeRegistration registration) in <filename unknown>:line 0
   at System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[TSource,TResult].MoveNext () in <filename unknown>:line 0
   at System.Linq.Enumerable+<CastIterator>c__Iterator17`1[TResult].MoveNext () in <filename unknown>:line 0
   at Nancy.Routing.RouteCache.BuildCache (IEnumerable`1 modules) in <filename unknown>:line 0
   at Nancy.Routing.RouteCache..ctor (INancyModuleCatalog moduleCatalog, INancyContextFactory contextFactory, IRouteSegmentExtractor routeSegmentExtractor, IRouteDescriptionProvider routeDescriptionProvider, ICultureService cultureService, IEnumerable`1 routeMetadataProviders) in <filename unknown>:line 0
   at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:lambda_method (System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure,object[])
   at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer.ConstructType (System.Type requestedType, System.Type implementationType, System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo constructor, Nancy.TinyIoc.NamedParameterOverloads parameters, Nancy.TinyIoc.ResolveOptions options) in <filename unknown>:line 0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer.ConstructType (System.Type requestedType, System.Type implementationType, System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo constructor, Nancy.TinyIoc.NamedParameterOverloads parameters, Nancy.TinyIoc.ResolveOptions options) in <filename unknown>:line 0
   at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer.ConstructType (System.Type requestedType, System.Type implementationType, System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo constructor, Nancy.TinyIoc.ResolveOptions options) in <filename unknown>:line 0
   at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer+SingletonFactory.GetObject (System.Type requestedType, Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer container, Nancy.TinyIoc.NamedParameterOverloads parameters, Nancy.TinyIoc.ResolveOptions options) in <filename unknown>:line 0
   at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer.ResolveInternal (Nancy.TinyIoc.TypeRegistration registration, Nancy.TinyIoc.NamedParameterOverloads parameters, Nancy.TinyIoc.ResolveOptions options) in <filename unknown>:line 0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer.ConstructType (System.Type requestedType, System.Type implementationType, System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo constructor, Nancy.TinyIoc.NamedParameterOverloads parameters, Nancy.TinyIoc.ResolveOptions options) in <filename unknown>:line 0
   at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer.ConstructType (System.Type requestedType, System.Type implementationType, System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo constructor, Nancy.TinyIoc.ResolveOptions options) in <filename unknown>:line 0
   at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer+SingletonFactory.GetObject (System.Type requestedType, Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer container, Nancy.TinyIoc.NamedParameterOverloads parameters, Nancy.TinyIoc.ResolveOptions options) in <filename unknown>:line 0
   at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer.ResolveInternal (Nancy.TinyIoc.TypeRegistration registration, Nancy.TinyIoc.NamedParameterOverloads parameters, Nancy.TinyIoc.ResolveOptions options) in <filename unknown>:line 0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer.ConstructType (System.Type requestedType, System.Type implementationType, System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo constructor, Nancy.TinyIoc.NamedParameterOverloads parameters, Nancy.TinyIoc.ResolveOptions options) in <filename unknown>:line 0
   at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer.ConstructType (System.Type requestedType, System.Type implementationType, System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo constructor, Nancy.TinyIoc.ResolveOptions options) in <filename unknown>:line 0
   at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer+SingletonFactory.GetObject (System.Type requestedType, Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer container, Nancy.TinyIoc.NamedParameterOverloads parameters, Nancy.TinyIoc.ResolveOptions options) in <filename unknown>:line 0
   at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer.ResolveInternal (Nancy.TinyIoc.TypeRegistration registration, Nancy.TinyIoc.NamedParameterOverloads parameters, Nancy.TinyIoc.ResolveOptions options) in <filename unknown>:line 0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer.ConstructType (System.Type requestedType, System.Type implementationType, System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo constructor, Nancy.TinyIoc.NamedParameterOverloads parameters, Nancy.TinyIoc.ResolveOptions options) in <filename unknown>:line 0
   at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer.ConstructType (System.Type requestedType, System.Type implementationType, System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo constructor, Nancy.TinyIoc.ResolveOptions options) in <filename unknown>:line 0
   at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer+SingletonFactory.GetObject (System.Type requestedType, Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer container, Nancy.TinyIoc.NamedParameterOverloads parameters, Nancy.TinyIoc.ResolveOptions options) in <filename unknown>:line 0
   at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer.ResolveInternal (Nancy.TinyIoc.TypeRegistration registration, Nancy.TinyIoc.NamedParameterOverloads parameters, Nancy.TinyIoc.ResolveOptions options) in <filename unknown>:line 0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Nancy.Bootstrapper.NancyBootstrapperBase`1[TContainer].SafeGetNancyEngineInstance () in <filename unknown>:line 0
   at Nancy.Bootstrapper.NancyBootstrapperBase`1[TContainer].GetEngine () in <filename unknown>:line 0
   at Nancy.Hosting.Self.NancyHost..ctor (INancyBootstrapper bootstrapper, Nancy.Hosting.Self.HostConfiguration configuration, System.Uri[] baseUris) in <filename unknown>:line 0
   at Nancy.Hosting.Self.NancyHost..ctor (System.Uri[] baseUris) in <filename unknown>:line 0
   at Reflect.Web.v2.MainClass.Main (System.String[] args) in <filename unknown>:line 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Going all the way to the right shows:
Unable to resolve type: Nancy.Routing.RouteCache ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
   at System.Exception..ctor (System.String message, System.Exception innerException) in :line 0

RouteCache is usually what triggers the resolution of your Nancy Modules.
It seems there's a NullReferenceException in the constructor of one of your modules